# When Does Django Perform the Database Lookup?

Tags: sql, django, filtered-lookup

From the following code:

```
dvdList = Dvd.objects.filter(title = someDvdTitle)[:10]

for dvd in dvdList:
    result = "Title: "+dvd.title+" @ "+dvd.price+"."
```

When does Django do the lookup? Maybe it's just paranoia, but it seems if I comment out the for loop, it returns a lot quicker. Is the first line setting up a filter and then the for loop executes it, or am I completely muddled up? What actually happens with those lines of code?

EDIT:

What would happen if I limited the objects.filter to '1000' and then implemented a counter in the for loop that broke out of it after 10 iterations. Would that effectively only get 10 values or 1000?

Comment: @_bravado - does my answer provide enough info for "What actually happens with those lines of code?" now? You edited your question after I first posted. I can try and explain more if it'd help.

Comment: Yes, that was perfect. However I edited it again with an additional question. I just wanted to make absolutely certain what would happen if I limited the filter to 1000, but only iterated in a for loop 10 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django querysets are evaluated lazily, so yes, the query won't actually be executed until you try and get values out of it (as you're doing in the `for` loop).

From the docs:

> You can evaluate a QuerySet in the following ways:
>
> *Iteration*. A QuerySet is iterable, and
>   it executes its database query the
>   first time you iterate over it. For
>   example, this will print the headline
>   of all entries in the database:
>
> ```
> for e in Entry.objects.all():
>     print e.headline
> ```
>
> ...(snip)...

See [When Querysets are evaluated](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id1).

*Per your edit:*

If you limited the filter to 1000 and then implemented a counter in the for loop that broke out of it after 10 iterations, then you'd hit the database for all 1000 rows - Django has no way of knowing ahead of time exactly what you're going to do with the Queryset - it just knows that you want some data out of it, so evaluates the query string it's built up.

Answer (score 0):

It may be also good to evaluate all at once using `list()` or any other method of eval of the query. I find it to boost performance sometimes (no paying for the DB connections every time).

Find more info about when django evaluates [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/).